# Shuffle characters in an array in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, random, character, shuffle

Using an online tutorial I worked on trying to shuffle characters in an array.  The tutorial I used was using integers and also didn't include any user input, but when I try and replicate it and change it to do what I would like in the code I made below something is not working out.

There is no error message at all.  When I run the program it only prompts the user to enter a word and then ends.

Just in case you can't understand what I wanted from the code I would like the user to be able to insert a word and then the 'shuffled' word is printed at the end. (ex. Hello > elHol)

I am still a very new programmer and have a very hard time with the subject in general so please understand any 'dumb' mistakes you'll likely come across that I've made.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    char word[15];
    int i,length,j, temp;

     srand(time(NULL));

     printf("Insert word\n");
     scanf("%s", word);

     for(i=0; word[i] != '\0'; )
     {
        i = i + 1;
    }

     i = length;

     for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        j = (rand()%length);
        temp = word[i];
        word[i] = word[j];
        word[j] = temp;
    }

    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
         printf("%c", word[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix this line: i = length;

Answer (score 2):

Welcome ;). In addition to the other engineers's solution to your problem, I have modified your code not to use the temporary variable to swap.[ since you mentioned new programmer, i felt this should help to some extend. ;) ]

Look at the below source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char word[15];
    int i,length,j, temp;

     srand(time(NULL));

     printf("Insert word\n");
     scanf("%s", word);

     for(length=0; word[length++] != '\0';);
     for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        j = (rand()%length);
        word[i] = word[i] ^ word[j];
        word[j] = word[i] ^ word[j];
        word[i] = word[i] ^ word[j];
    }

    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
         printf("%c", word[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the '^' symbol.  What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

Few changes to your code:

Make `temp` as char :

```
char temp;
```

Assign `length` to `i` you are doing it the other way where you are assigning i to length and since length is uninitialized and you are using it this value to assign to some other variable causes undefined behavior.

```
length = i;
```

Comment: @Casey does it work now just by correcting the assignment of `length` ?

Comment: @chouaib Cool.. your wordings gave me that impression :)

Comment: at all dude ;) I even mentioned that in my answer, but I'me quite sure it won't work even after doing these changes

Comment: @Gopi: can you please explain why you changed `temp` from `int` to `char`? how did that contribute in fixing the code?

Comment: @chouaib Why waster memory by using int instead of getting the job done using `char`?

Answer (score -1):

Try my revision of your code! 
This will fix the spaces and lost of vowels in printing the shuffle string. SORRY FOR MY BAD ENLISH :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char word[100];
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i,j,length,temp;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",&word);

    for(i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; ++i){

    length = i;
    }
    length+=1;
    i = length;
    while(--i>0){
        j = (rand()%length);
        temp= word[j];
        word[j]= word[i];
        word[i]= temp;
    }

   for(i=0; i<=length; i++)
    {
         printf("%c", word[i]);
    }
}
```